# Perfect Continuous Aspect

Tags: aspect, perfect-continuous

The perfect continuous aspect is used for the end of an ongoing action. How is it applicable in the two instances as follows?

1. I had been working in the office when 9/11 happened. (Here I worked even after the incident. This means the ongoing action never stopped.)
2. He will be tired when we meet him because he will have been exercising so hard. (Here as well, there is no implication that he will stop his exercise after the meet. That means he may or may not continue his practice.)

Thanks
brp7

Comment: What's your doubt??

Comment: #1 looks highly suspect to me. We'd need a much more complete context (of preceding text) to be definitive, but almost certainly it would be better to say *I **was** working in the office when 9/11 happened.* Note that #2 carries the very strong implication that he will have *finished* exercising by the time we meet him. If that wasn't the intention, it would be *...because he **will be exercising** so hard*  (which is "agnostic" as to whether he will stop exercising as soon as we arrive).

Comment: ...but the *semantics* of something like *I had been living in the UK for several years before I applied for citizenship* very strongly implies I continued to live there afterwards. Whereas *We had been "living in sin" for several years before we got married* obviously entails (*forces* the interpretation) that we ***didn't*** continue living sin after the mentioned activity. And if you say *I've been here all day*, that obviously can't imply you've left (and probably doesn't imply you're about to leave either). Context is everything,

Comment: I happened to be at home on 9/11, but I was recently talking about it with a former colleague and she said that they had all stopped work in our office when the shocking news came through. So the first sentence could mean that the writer broke off from that day's work, not that they left their job.

Comment: @fumblefingers The confusion arises as the perfect continuous aspect is the stopping of an ongoing action. Can we say future perfect continuous expresses some duration of an event before it stops OR another event interrupts it (the first may continue as well)
I have made some other examples where the first action may continue. 
1) By evening, I will have been practicing for two hours. (By evening, I will have finished two hours of practice, but I will still continue practicing after the evening.)  cont.

Comment: @Sam  2) I will have been cutting the grass in my yard for a while when you arrive. (I intend to cut the grass even after your arrival.)

Comment: @brp7 It implies (you have not yet completed the two hours of practice; you are currently in the process of practicing,)and you will continue to do so until the evening, at which point you will have practiced for two hours.

Comment: Syntactically, I can't see that ***when 9/11 happened*** is any different to, say, ***yesterday*** as a noun phrase identifying some specific time in the past. So just as you can't start a conversation with  *I **had been working** from home **yesterday***, it's not obvious to me what context you have in mind to justify using Past Perfect *I **had been working** in the office **when 9/11 happened***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fully agree with you. It should be past continuous.  Appreciate it if you could look into the other two. 1)  By evening, I will have been practicing for two hours.  2) I will have been cutting the grass in my yard for a while when you arrive.

Comment: I already said in my first comment that #2 carries the very strong implication that he will have finished exercising by the time we meet him. Your ideas about "Perfect Continuous" implying anything about whether / when the specified action *stops* are mistaken, as made clear by my second comment. What else is still confusing you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers "He was tired because he had been exercising so hard.
This sentence emphasizes that he was tired because he had been exercising over a period of time. It is possible that he was still exercising at that moment OR that he had just finished. source: https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfectcontinuous.html

Comment: @brp7: Your link includes the potentially misleading statement *We use the past perfect continuous to show that something started in the past and **continued up until** another time in the past.* What they mean is ***and was still ongoing***, not ***and then stopped***. As pointed out in my second comment, past perfect continuous tells us something *started **before**, and was still ongoing **at*** some time in the past. It says nothing about whether/when the activity *stopped* - that can only be determined by context and pragmatics.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the past perfect to be idiomatic here:

> I **had been** working in the office when 9/11 happened.

The simple past continuous would be idiomatic there as the ongoing work in the office  was interrupted by what happened at a particular moment on the morning of 9/11:

> I was working in the office when the attack on 9/11 took place.

Consider:

> I had been working in that office *for only three weeks* when the attack on the morning of 9/11 took place.

There, the past perfect continuous is used *in combination with a time phrase that gives the inchoate time-span definition*, and that definition establishes a terminus that precedes the attack that **took place**.

With **he will have been exercising**, his exercise will have come to an end either coincident with, or immediately before, their arrival. **will be exercising** would be used to indicate that the exercise will be ongoing when they arrive.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you regarding that example. What would you say about the other two examples? Thanks!

Comment: @brp7 I don't know what you're referring to with "the other two examples".

Comment: I did not know that you didn't have access to the initial answers and comments. Here we go...  1) By evening, I will have been practicing for two hours. 2) I will have been cutting the grass in my yard for a while when you arrive.

Comment: Both sentences are idiomatic, although "evening" is not a precise time, so it's a little iffy on the semantic level.   Substitute  "dinner time" or "bed time" or any other time that is more definite than "evening" and "for two hours" will be more plausible.

Comment: Does the first one mean I may continue practicing after the evening, and the second one means I may continue cutting the grass after your arrival? Why I am asking is that  Perfect Continuous is the stopping of an ongoing action.

Comment: The first one says nothing whatsoever, explicit or implicit, about  continuing to practice  into the evening or ceasing practice when evening arrives. It is simply a statement about how long you will have been practicing measured up to that point in time.  Same with the second. It says nothing about continuing to mow or ceasing to mow.

Comment: *He thought to himself, I **have been mowing** for hours and I'm so tired, but there's still more mowing to do.*  We don't know whether he finished the job of mowing or quit because he was tired.  The perfect continuous is silent in that regard.  The phrase **for hours** is measured from the time he began mowing (which he knows) up to the time of the utterance.

Comment: As I said, "Why I am asking is that the Perfect Continuous aspect (any tense) is the stopping of an ongoing action."  I understand the sentence does not say anything about continuing or stopping after evening. Now if I write "I had been living in the UK for many years before I applied for citizenship," it strongly implies I continued to live there afterward.  In that case, where is the stopping of continuing action as per the definition of the Perfect continuous aspect? Now, this getting a little embarrassing with so many comments. It is fine. I would try some other place. Thanks.

Comment: In your original example you were going to "meet" someone. A meeting with someone would (normally) put an end to what they were doing before you arrived. However, if you go to *observe* someone, they may be continuing to do what they were doing. *When you go to see her swimming, bear in mind that she will have been swimming for several hours and she may seem a little slow.*

Comment: In your citizenship example, there is no strong implication *in the verb tense itself* that you continued to live in the UK after applying for citizenship. That implication may exist in the context  (it would be normal) but it is not entailed in the tense.  Just as in my comment directly above regarding the meeting. He may continue to exercise during your meeting, though it would be very unusual.  *I had been living in the UK for several years before I applied for citizenship; but there was a glitch in the database and they confused me with another person and  immediately deported me.*